# Difference in usage and connotation between "attenuate" and "extenuate"

Tags: differences, verbs

What is the difference between *attenuate* and *extenuate* in terms of their usage and connotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, to *[attenuate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_%28disambiguation%29)* is to dilute[1], and to *extenuate* is to excuse.  While one [sense of extenuate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extenuate) is "*To make thin or slender; to draw out so as to lessen the thickness,*" the sense "*To lessen; to palliate; to lessen or weaken the force of; to diminish the conception of, as crime, guilt, faults, ills, accusations, etc.*" is rather more commonly used.

[1] From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_%28disambiguation%29):  "Attenuation is the gradual loss in intensity of any kind of flux through a medium."  From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attenuate): "To reduce in size, force, value, amount, or degree; ... To weaken; ... To rarefy."

(I see that instead of "rarefy" being an alternative spelling of "[rarify](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rarify)", wiktionary says it's the other way around.)

Note, many english.stackexchange denizens regard questions like the above (which is easily answered via websites like wiktionary) as unsuitable questions.

Comment: I could quibble slightly with the exact meanings, but this is right. The main point is that **they are two completely different words**. No real overlap in meaning at all.